# How do I unlock a read-only Word document form?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

Someone sent me a Word doc that consists of a form full of checkboxes and freeform fields.  I am trying to insert an image version of my signature and a few extra freeform text fields so I don't have to print it and fax it, but the document appears locked.  I went to Developer > Protect Document and made sure Unrestricted Access is checked, but I still can't modify the form.

I am using Word 2007 and this is saved as .doc, probably 97-2003.  How can I unlock this thing?

**Edit**:  Also, all but a few of the ribbon menu items are disabled.  I can't change page layout, text formatting, or anything that pertains to modifying the document.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I unlock a Microsoft .docx document?](https://superuser.com/questions/486844/how-can-i-unlock-a-microsoft-docx-document)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said it sounds like the file is locked. To open it you need to went to Developer > Protect Document, like you do, but then to enter to "Restrict Formatting and Editing". Now click Stop Protection at the bottom of the task pane and enter the password (if you know it, if the "Stop Protection" doesn't appear the file is not locked).

If the file is locked and you don't know the password you can try to use [this guide](http://www.gmayor.com/Remove_Password.htm) to unlock it (disclaimer: I don't try this guide and I don't know if it works or not (but according to the comments in forum where I found it (with a brief search on Google) he is doing the job)).

If the "Stop Protection" doesn't appear and you still can't edit, comment here and I'll try to help more.

Comment: Good one.  `In Word 2007/2010 - Insert Tab - Object > Text from File` is the one that worked for me.  Everyone should understand, though, that this method may not preserve formatting.  I had to redo the margins since they didn't carry over, but it served its purpose to unlock a form so I could fill it out and send it back.

Comment: My document is restricted and there is no "Stop Protection" button. Here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/oysazu3.png Can you please describe what to do in this scenario? Thanks!

Comment: Just after I posted my comment I found that the "Stop Protection" button is in tiny font at the bottom of the right pane. Poor design but still works I suppose.

Answer (score 10):

1. Open your document in Word, then use "Save as..." to save it in ".xml" format.
2. Open the .xml file in wordpad, notepad, emacs, or other text editor of your choice.
3. Search for the string w:enforcement="1" (or w:enforcement="on").
4. Replace the "1" with a "0" (or replace "on" with "off") to disable enforcement. (This step unlocks the document.)
5. Save the .xml document from your text editor.
6. Open the .xml document in Word.
7. Choose "Save as..." and save it as a .doc or .docx file.

   Your original Word document can now be edited normally. Enjoy!

Comment: Totally worked! No password needed.