# How to remove the password of a .docx document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, password-recovery

Following advice from [horatio](https://superuser.com/users/60906/horatio) and [stuartd](https://superuser.com/users/1388/stuartd) for the question [How can I unlock a Microsoft .docx document?](https://superuser.com/questions/486844/how-can-i-unlock-a-microsoft-docx-document) , I've tried unzipping the .docx file, but it won't work.

When I try to open it says "The archive is either in unknown format or damaged"

I've tried using the word password recovery and word password remover, but it's still not working. I've changed the extension file into .doc instead of .docx, but it says that the file type is not supported.
How can I open it??? Is it possible to unzip an encrypted .docx?? If so, please help

Comment: You can try and brute force the password then unprotect the document

Comment: Did you create the document? And can you open and view it?

Comment: Do you know the password and just want to learn how to unset it, or are you trying to crack the document?